# Why group by is needed for where

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate

I'm no developer, but need to make this work before I can get a developer to help...
I have the following; which works, but I need an WHERE into the select to make it correct and it tells me I need to add to the group by. When I do that it 'duplicates' the results.

What works:

```
Select  ALTEXTCUSTREF
    ,(SELECT AVG(C.SALESPRICE*C.QTY)) AS Budget
    ,select SUM(B.LEDGERSALESAMOUNT) as Labour 
from SMMACTIVITIES AS A
LEFT JOIN PROJEMPLTRANS AS B ON A.ACTIVITYNUMBER=B.ACTIVITYNUMBER
LEFT JOIN PROJFORECASTEMPL AS C ON A.ACTIVITYNUMBER=C.ACTIVITYNUMBER
WHERE A.ACTIVITYNUMBER LIKE '1234%'
group by A.ALTEXTCUSTREF, C.ACTIVITYNUMBER
```

but I need to put a condition on the B.LEDGERSALESAMOUNT so I did the following;

```
Select  ALTEXTCUSTREF
    ,(SELECT AVG(C.SALESPRICE*C.QTY)) AS Budget
    ,(select SUM(B.LEDGERSALESAMOUNT) where B.CATEGORYID NOT LIKE 'P_%')  as Labour 
from SMMACTIVITIES AS A
LEFT JOIN PROJEMPLTRANS AS B ON A.ACTIVITYNUMBER=B.ACTIVITYNUMBER
LEFT JOIN PROJFORECASTEMPL AS C ON A.ACTIVITYNUMBER=C.ACTIVITYNUMBER
WHERE A.ACTIVITYNUMBER LIKE '1234%'
group by A.ALTEXTCUSTREF, C.ACTIVITYNUMBER
```

And I get this error:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4 Column 'PROJEMPLTRANS.CATEGORYID'
>   is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

But if I put B.CATEGORYID into the Group by I get the lines of the ALTEXTCUSTREF splitting out which is incorrect.

Please help. I'm stuck and running out of time.

Comment: Remove those inner selects, just leave aggregated functions, they are unnecessary, and remove c.ActivityNumber from group by ,,, you error is showing because you have "where b.CategoryId NOT LIKE 'p_%'" in your inner select, switch to case

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That query is product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

Editted as OP's new intention

```
    SELECT bg.altextcustref
    ,bg.activitynumber
    ,bg.budget
    ,lb.labour
FROM
(
    SELECT altextcustref
        ,activitynumber
        ,AVG(c.salesprice * c.qty) AS budget
    FROM smmactivities AS a
    LEFT JOIN projforecastempl AS c 
    ON a.activitynumber = c.activitynumber
    WHERE a.activitynumber LIKE '1234%'
    GROUP BY a.altextcustref, c.activitynumber
) AS bg
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT altextcustref
        ,activitynumber
        ,SUM(b.ledgersalesamount) AS labour
    FROM smmactivities AS a
    LEFT JOIN projempltrans AS b 
    ON a.activitynumber = b.activitynumber
    WHERE a.activitynumber LIKE '1234%'
        AND b.categoryid NOT LIKE 'P_%'
    GROUP BY a.altextcustref, c.activitynumber
) AS lb
ON bg.altextcustref = lb.altextcustref 
    AND bg.activitynumber = lb.activitynumber;
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But now my amounts are all double what they should be. Is this the way I've done the join?

Comment: @Tooold It may be because of your `JOIN` statements, you should check for your data. Try same query but use `SELECT *` and delete `GROUP BY` clause, add `ORDER BY a.altextcustref, c.activitynumber;` to check for duplicate rows

Comment: I did that, and it's when I add JOIN PROJFORECASTEMPL AS C ON SMMACTIVITIES.ACTIVITYNUMBER=C.ACTIVITYNUMBER that the values double. I've tried every other join and it doesn't make a difference. Any clues for someone without any???

Comment: @Tooold It means that you should calculate `budget` and `labour` separately (using LEFT JOIN projforecastempl for  `budget`, projempltrans for  `labour`), then join two result on `a.altextcustref, c.activitynumber`. Try using my editted answer.